# Understanding "よりを戻す" and "止めておこう"

Tags: grammar, words, て-form, idioms

> I don't think us getting together tonight is such a good idea.
>
> やっぱり今夜、よりを戻すのは止めておこう。

I would like to understand this sentence better, specifically the (idiomatic?) expression, "よりを戻す." I will parse the parts I am not sure of below to see if I grasp it correctly:

"やっぱり"  "after all."

"よりを戻す" is an idiom(?) meaning "get back together."

"止めておこう"  "Should let pass/should let the matter drop/let's quit"

If these are acceptable, how does "よりを戻す" express "get back together"?

And does the おこう in "止めておこう" derive from 置く?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you correctly understood, よりを戻す is an idiom meaning for a broken couple to get back together.

[[縒]{よ}る](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E7%B8%92%E3%82%8B&stype=1&dtype=0&dname=0ss) means “to twist threads together to make a thicker string.”  [[縒]{よ}りを戻す](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?dtype=0&dname=0ss&p=%E3%82%88%E3%82%8A%E3%82%92%E3%82%82%E3%81%A9%E3%81%99) literally means to undo this process and turn a string into several threads apart.  This may sound like the opposite of getting back together (certainly it does sound like the opposite to me), but I guess that the analogy here is that “twisting” refers to the conflict between a couple, and removing the twist corresponds to getting back together.

おこう in [止]{や}めておこう is etymologically derived from 置く (to put), but here …ておく means “to do … for now.”  In this context, よりを戻すのをやめておく means to avoid getting back together for now.