# What is the difference between あるまい and　ありません？

Tags: grammar, particles, verbs

From what I understand, they both mean "is not". But from what I've been able to gather from the few times I've heard it, it seems that あるまい may not be as strong or definitive as ありません. Am I on the right track here? Also, can まい be used with any verb ex: 飲むまい or just with ある?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- `ません` expresses negation in polite form.
- `まい` expresses a guess or intentional future, both in negation. So its entailment is weaker than `ません`, but implies willingness. A close counterpart in English is `shall not` as opposed to `will not`. `まい` can be used with other verbs as well.

> もう酒は飲みません
>   'I will not drink liquor any more.' (polite)
>
> もう酒は飲むまい
>   'I shall not drink liquor any more.' (guess)
>   'I shall not drink liquor any more.' (declaration)

Answer (score 13):

I think あるまい is a literary version of ないだろう. 
飲むまい means 飲まないだろう(I think s/he won't drink)/飲まないでおこう(I won't drink), no?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Chocolate: What does `おこう` mean in your example sentence?

Comment: @dotnetN00b-san, Tsuyoshi-san's answer will help http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4748/1016