# Using にしておいてやる to say "Let's pretend"?

Tags: meaning, future, interpretation

> 今日のところは引き分けって事にしておいてやるっ！

I saw this sentence in the dialect of a videogame between character A and B.
B says this line after being defeated by A.
I think B is saying that they should pretend this (defeat) is a "tie" (Because he seems to be arrogant) but I'm not sure how the おいて part shows some kind of preparation for the future. Would it be ok to omit おいて form the sentence? or will change the meaning completely.

His entire speech was:

> 「ハァ…ハァ…こんなに熱くなったのは久しぶりだぜ…
>   　今日のところは引き分けって事にしておいてやるっ！
>   　今度オレとやる時まで、誰にもやられるんじゃねぇーぞ！じゃー、あばよっ！」

Comment: It's more like "I'll generously call it a tie!" rather than "Let's pretend it's a tie!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

～ておく has [several meanings](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5216/5010), and in this case it means "to leave (status)" or "to do (something) **for now / for the time being**". 窓を開けておく can mean both "to leave the window open" and "to open the window beforehand."

So saying ておく here implies he is going to win eventually in the future. Dropping おく and saying 引き分けってことにしてやる will not largely change the meaning in this particular case, because he's already said 今日のところは ("for today", "for now"), which also implies the situation will be different in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Bob didn't want to admit he was almost defeated by Alice. If they kept on a battle, she would win against him. So, he said that phrase as a meaning of "I'll let you off today." to avoid defeat.
Also, we can omit おいて in this sentence and it is almost the same as original one, that is "今日のところは引き分けって事にしてやるっ！" also means "I'll let you off today".　
Personally, I think it seems that Bob can still afford to win the battle to some extent if we omit "おいて" in such sentences.
この辺にしておいてやるよ。/ I'll let you off. (Bob was almost defeated?)
この辺にしてやるよ。/ I'll let you off. (Bob could afford to win and expects Alice to become stronger?)