# っといても after a verb

Tags: grammar, particles, sentence

What does っといても mean after a verb, I've seen it several times. I'm guessing it's a slang form or a shortened form? I know that ても means "even if" (roughly), and I've seen って a lot so wasn't sure if it's some slang form of that?

Sentence:

> 冬なら生の塩漬け肉を外にほっぽっといても

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the breakdown:

- [ほっぽる](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%94%BE%E3%81%A3%E3%81%BD%E3%82%8B): a colloquial godan verb that in this context means "to leave (alone)"
- ほっぽって: the te-form of ほっぽる
- ほっぽっておく: the te-form followed by the subsidiary verb おく, which means "to do something for the time being" here. See [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5216/5010) or [this article](http://maggiesensei.com/2017/04/06/new-how-to-use-v%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8A%E3%81%8F-te-oku/).
- ほっぽっとく: the contracted form of ほっぽっておく. See [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18159/5010).
- ほっぽっといても: the temo-form of above, which adds the meaning of "even if" (-ておく/-とく conjugates like a godan verb)

So 外にほっぽっといても (or 外にほっぽっておいても) means "even if you leave (it) out in the open (for some time)".