# Meaning of しとくとして in this sentence

Tags: particles, reading-comprehension

> とりあえずさっきの子にLINEしとくとして…
>
> 軽く飯食べって帰ろ…

I take he's saying he'll contact the girl from before with LINE, but what is しとくとして?

しておく+ として? How does it work?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is something like this:

> しとくとして -> しておく + として -> しておく + とする (in て form)

So it means something like: I will make sure to put things in place (in LINE) so that (I will contact the girl from before). Maybe by saving the contact in a particular way or something. Dunno about LINE.

See [this one](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/34137/what-does-verb%E3%81%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-mean) for the meaning of とする.

Comment: `Dunno about LINE` -- If you mean you don't know the app "LINE": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(software)

Answer (score 1):

しとくとして is short for しておくとして.

- -ておく is a subsidiary verb that has several meanings. In this case, it adds a nuance "to do something and then leave it in the state" or "to do it for now (and think later)". It contracts to -とく (see [this chart](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18159/5010)).

  - [What is the true meaning of「ておく」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/84773/5010)
- -とする is "to decide to ～".

  - [What does verb+とする mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34137/5010)

> とりあえずさっきの子にLINEしとくとして、…
> For now, I'll send a message (via LINE) to her, and ...

The implication is "I'll worry about this later".